# Katalon Studio: How do I parameterize automated tests

Tags: testing, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I am testing a web application using Katalon Studio and the test steps include loading a file into the application via a file chooser. I'm using `WebUI.uploadFile()` to do this, but I have discovered that it takes **only** an absolute path.

This is a major problem because we have automated nightly testing run via Jenkins. Currently in the groovy test script, I have a hard-coded path to a test input file that is located in a specific directory on my workstation. This works fine when I'm running the test on my machine, but is obviously not going to work on any other system, including the Jenkins system.

It would be extremely useful if I could either

- access Katalon provided built-in variables (if they exist)
- specify a relative path
- reference an environment variable
- some other technique?

Any ideas on how to solve this problem would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use following function to get project directory to generate relative path RunConfiguration.getProjectDir()

Comment: OK, that worked to get me the project directory. The directory where the test files are located is in a relative path. E.g. `<project dir>/../../inputs/<test file>`. I tried to create the path to the file by appending to the path returned by `RunConfiguration.getProjectDir()`, but when executed, got an error indicating my path was not canonical. I'm not familiar with groovy - can I write a function that would allow me to edit the path returned by `RunConfiguration.getProjectDir()` to reconstruct the path I need?

Comment: `RunConfiguration.getProjectDir()` returns a string so you can just append the rest of the path like `RunConfiguration.getProjectDir()+"/../../inputs/<test file>" `.

Answer (score 1):

To answer one of your points, you can reference the environment variables ("HOME" variable in this case) by:

```
${System.getenv('HOME')}
```